# Xamarin Forms how to add behaviors to custom control

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls, behavior

I have created a custom control,which is a `ContentView` with a `Label` and an `Entry`

The `xaml` of the custom controls looks like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidationControl}, Path=Caption}"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ValidationControl}, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The code behind of the custom control looks like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CaptionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Caption), typeof(string), typeof(ValidationEntry), default(string));

public string Caption
{
    get => (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty);
    set => SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty ValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Value), typeof(string), typeof(ValidationEntry), default(string));

public string Value
{
    get => (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}
```

I’m using the custom control in the following way

```
<controls:ValidationEntry Caption=”Name:” Value="{Binding FullName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My question is how to add behaviors to the custom control?
I would like to add them in the place that I’m using the control. i.e.

```
<controls:ValidationEntry Caption="Name:"
                          Value="{Binding FullName, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <controls:ValidationEntry.EntryBehaviors>
        <behaviors:EntryLengthValidatorBehavior IgnoreSpaces="True"/>
    </controls:ValidationEntry.EntryBehaviors>
</controls:ValidationEntry>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a behaviors directly, I add a NumericValidationBehavior in my custom entry to check the data if it is double.If type of the data is not double, the color of text will be set to red.

[image]

Here is xaml code.

```
<StackLayout>
<local:MyEntry   local:NumericValidationBehavior.AttachBehavior="true">


</local:MyEntry>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is NumericValidationBehavior.cs

```
     public static class NumericValidationBehavior
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AttachBehaviorProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "AttachBehavior",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(NumericValidationBehavior),
            false,
            propertyChanged: OnAttachBehaviorChanged);

    public static bool GetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (bool)view.GetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachBehavior(BindableObject view, bool value)
    {
        view.SetValue(AttachBehaviorProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var entry = view as Entry;
        if (entry == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool attachBehavior = (bool)newValue;
        if (attachBehavior)
        {
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        }
    }

    static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        double result;
        bool isValid = double.TryParse(args.NewTextValue, out result);
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = isValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I create a custom view with ContentView

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BeHavDemo.MyView">
 <ContentView.Content>
     <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="xxxx"/>
        <Entry Text="eeeee" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Then I create a behavior.

```
    public  class MyBeha : Behavior<MyView>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(BindableObject view)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(view);

        var myview=view as MyView;
        StackLayout stackLayout = (StackLayout)myview.Content;

        Label label = (Label)stackLayout.Children[0];
       Entry entry=(Entry) stackLayout.Children[1];

    }
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach! I haven't checked it if this works but I will do it shortly. It's not exactly as I described it and also not sure if this behavior can be used outside of a custom control. In any case it's an interesting solution.

Comment: It doesn’t work. The problem is that in `NumericValidationBehavior` and in `OnAttachBehaviorChanged` you cast the `BindableObject view` as an `Entry`. My custom control is not an `Entry` but it contains an `Entry` and it’s just an example so it might contains 2 entries (i.e. a control for phone with a national prefix and the number). It might work if I put the behavior inside the `Entry` of my custom control and databind the `AttachBehavior` so I can turn it on or off but it’s a bit cumbersome. I was searching for a way to add behaviors the way that I described it at the end of my post.

Comment: @Dimitris If you want to set a behavior for a combined view, you can achieve this behavior in custom renderer, achieve this behavior for different platforms, like this 
 thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-android, judege the `control`'s status and set the effect for this `Control`.

Comment: Lu Why do I need to create a custom renderer? There is nothing on the control that is platform dependent! All I'm asking is how to deal the behaviors list in a custom control.

Comment: @Dimitris I am so sorry, I am confused with another link.I create a custom view, you can see my update answer, I can get the entry and label by BindableObject